# Camel SMPP custom SMS port

Tags: apache-camel, smpp, jsmpp

I'm currently trying to send a SMS with Camel SMPP but I'm failing on sending it to a specific destination port.
Actually nothing port related happens on my SMPP server.
Here is my current code in my Processor :

```
exchange.getOut().setHeader("CamelSmppAlphabet", Alphabet.ALPHA_8_BIT.value());
exchange.getOut().setHeader("CamelSmppDataCoding", 4);

short destport = 5000;
short srcport = 0;

Map<java.lang.Short, java.lang.Short> optParameters = new HashMap<java.lang.Short, java.lang.Short>();
optParameters.put(OptionalParameter.Tag.DESTINATION_PORT.code(), destport);
optParameters.put(OptionalParameter.Tag.SOURCE_PORT.code(), srcport);

exchange.getOut().setHeader("CamelSmppOptionalParameter", optParameters);
```

Am I doing something wrong ? If so how am I supposed to send my message to a specific destination Port ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I would like to know it too, as I will get a part of your work ;). Do you think we can try via XMPP or SIP ?

Comment: @Alex Didn't try any of those. As for the Camel SMPP Destination Port, after weeks of research, I'm pretty sure this is an issue in Camel and this is kinda "unimplemented". I looked at the source code and didn't find any interpretation of the Tag. Only solution might be using jsmpp directly...